# Is it possible to create composed objects in yEd without the group frame?

Tags: yed

Is it possible to create composed objects in yEd? In a conventional editor I would use the "group" feature, but in yEd it creates a big frame with a title and minimize button:

[image]

Can I have just the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked at the [yEd Q&A](https://yed.yworks.com/support/qa/2239/create-invisible-group).

To achieve what you want you need to:

- Select the group
- Set the Fill Color to "No Color"
- Set the Line Color to "No Color"
- Uncheck the label visibility
- Go to File -> Preferences -> Display and set Group State Icon to "Never Show Group State"

This is the result with the settings:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible additionally to "lock" group, so I can't move parts separately anymore?

Comment: Perhaps you can do some research first (Google, Yandex) and, if that doesn't give you satisfactory results, then come here to ask a new question? You have plenty of reputation, so I assume you know that when asking a question you should show what you've tried or how you've looked for a solution.